# How to structure/create a table in Postgres where columns have many-to-many references?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two tables: a cruise and a proposal table.

A cruise can have multiple proposal references to it and a proposal can have multiple cruise references to it.

How would I go about it?

Ideally, what I want to be able to do is when I query a cruise, I can see the list of proposals linked to it, and when I query the proposals, I can also see the list of cruises linked to it.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You implement many-to-many relationships using an intersection table which holds FK references to the two tables